# How do they represent the average movie's rating on imdb, rotten tomatoes?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, node.js

Alright lets say the average rating of a movie/restaurant is 4.3. On the show page you have the name of the object, the description, the contact, images etc etc... then you have the average rating represented in stars. In the object's model you store the rating from every user and with simple mathematical formula you calculate the average. But what I am curious about is how do they represent 4.3 which is 4 stars and a little bit less than 4.5? Isn't it too much to have stored 50 png images? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can help, they'll do. But keep in mind that SO is a community that helps, and **no one will do all the work for you**. What have you tried so far ?... There are many snippets already that can match your needs, did you search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually much simpler than it seems. Imagine two elements, stacked on top of one another:

1. A row of gold stars
2. A row of gray stars

Then, with a simple image mask you can calculate in `js` the relative width of the `golden star` layer.

In greater detail, they actually use a sprite as the very basis:

[image]

Play with the width values and you'll see the full effect:

```js
document.querySelector(".one .gold").style.width = "83.5%";
document.querySelector(".two .gold").style.width = "56%";
```

```css
div{position:relative;height:12px;margin-bottom:10px;width: 140px;
    background:url('http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/rating/rating-list/sprite-1445387679._V_.png')0 -28px;
}

span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 12px;
  background-image: url('http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/rating/rating-list/sprite-1445387679._V_.png');
}

.gold{background-position: 0 -42px;}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <span class="gold"></span>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <span class="gold"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: One star is actually enough.